# MySQL: slow select without where and joins

Tags: mysql, performance, profiling

I have the following table:

```
| ticket | CREATE TABLE `ticket` (
  `ticket_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `owner_id` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `requester_id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_type` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(18) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime(3) NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime(3) NOT NULL,
  `eta` datetime(3) NOT NULL,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `office_id` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `department_id` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `requester` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `requester_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'IPDEPLOY',
  `assignment_group_id` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ticket_id`),
  KEY `idx_ticket_office_id` (`office_id`),
  KEY `idx_ticket_department_id` (`department_id`),
  KEY `idx_ticket_client_id` (`client_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3116172 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC ENCRYPTION='Y';

mysql> select count(*) from ticket;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1190895 |
+----------+
mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'ticket' \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: ticket
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Dynamic
           Rows: 1101291
 Avg_row_length: 375
    Data_length: 413089792
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 153468928
      Data_free: 6291456
 Auto_increment: 3121563
    Create_time: 2022-05-18 09:51:06
    Update_time: 2022-05-19 12:06:18
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options: row_format=DYNAMIC ENCRYPTION="Y"
        Comment:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Simple queries intermittently take considerable amount of time (around 30% of such queries take more than 500 ms (some take up to 3 sec)):

```
mysql> select * from ticket limit 20, 20;
...
20 rows in set (0.77 sec)
```

when profiling, all the time is spent in starting phase:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING WHERE QUERY_ID=37 order by duration DESC limit 2 \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           QUERY_ID: 37
                SEQ: 2
              STATE: starting
           DURATION: 0.760068
           CPU_USER: NULL
         CPU_SYSTEM: NULL
  CONTEXT_VOLUNTARY: NULL
CONTEXT_INVOLUNTARY: NULL
       BLOCK_OPS_IN: NULL
      BLOCK_OPS_OUT: NULL
      MESSAGES_SENT: NULL
  MESSAGES_RECEIVED: NULL
  PAGE_FAULTS_MAJOR: NULL
  PAGE_FAULTS_MINOR: NULL
              SWAPS: NULL
    SOURCE_FUNCTION: NULL
        SOURCE_FILE: NULL
        SOURCE_LINE: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           QUERY_ID: 37
                SEQ: 11
              STATE: Sending data
           DURATION: 0.000234
           CPU_USER: NULL
         CPU_SYSTEM: NULL
  CONTEXT_VOLUNTARY: NULL
CONTEXT_INVOLUNTARY: NULL
       BLOCK_OPS_IN: NULL
      BLOCK_OPS_OUT: NULL
      MESSAGES_SENT: NULL
  MESSAGES_RECEIVED: NULL
  PAGE_FAULTS_MAJOR: NULL
  PAGE_FAULTS_MINOR: NULL
              SWAPS: NULL
    SOURCE_FUNCTION: exec
        SOURCE_FILE: sql_executor.cc
        SOURCE_LINE: 195
```

MySQL manual doesn't say much about starting state: "The first stage at the beginning of statement execution.". How can I find out what MySQL is actually doing in this state? What might be the cause of such behaviour?

MySQL 5.7.27-30-57-log running on CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 inside a container in Azure. DB is not loaded at all.

innodb_buffer_pool_size is set to 12G

IOwait and prometheus metrics:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you post TEXT results of SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'ticket'; for consideration of why STARTING takes so long?

Comment: Could you post all the data displayed  when you saw 'starting' for your profiled query id.   Then we can compare it to this URL's  https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mysql/query-profiling/ example output. Thank you for providing the STS.

Comment: An alternative for condensed report is  - SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY n; for a 2 column display.

Comment: I don't have experience with `ENCRYPTION="Y"`, but I suspect that.  If that is the real query, it should touch only 2-3 blocks, which should not take 0.77 sec. (if unencrypted)

Comment: Those charts are pretty, but at what time was the query run?

Comment: Better yet, what date and time was each query run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we fixed this by setting wsrep_sync_wait to 0.